# Scroll to the open tab in jQuery Accordion control placed in its own DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I am using the [jQuery Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) control that resides in its own scrollable div:

```
<div id="mainSection">
    <div id="accordion">
    </div>
</div>
```

with CSS:

```
#mainSection{
    clear: both;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 4px 0px 0px 0px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 600px;
    border-top: thin solid #EEE;
}
```

The accordion control is initialized to open with a specific tab, as such:

```
    $("#accordion").accordion({
            collapsible: true,
            heightStyle: "content",
            active: nActiveTab
        });
```

The tabs for this accordion are added dynamically.

This works if the accordion doesn't have too many tabs. But if the accordion has, say, 100 tabs and I want to open the tab 99 at the very bottom (in my `nActiveTab` variable), when the accordion is created it is not scrolled down to that open tab 99.

Is there any way to make it scroll to it?

PS. Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35w6df1r/) for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always helpful to create a fiddlejs with your code.

Try adding that after your accordion code, and let me know how it works:

```
var activeTabOffset = $(".ui-accordion-header-active").offset().top;
var mainSectionHeight = $('#mainSection').height();

if (activeTabOffset > mainSectionHeight) {
    $('#mainSection').animate({scrollTop: activeTabOffset}, 1000);
}
```

What this will do is scroll your `mainSection` element down ( or up ) to the first active accordion. I didn't test it, but it should work.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/95g0L8pq/3/

Comment: Thanks. I think you added too many closing brackets there. But still it doesn't work. Btw, thanks for reminding me. I added the fiddle to my original post.

Comment: I updated the answer and fiddle. It's working for me. Try again and let me know

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to prevent it from scrolling if it doesn't have to? This will show the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/95g0L8pq/1/

Comment: Thanks. Appreciate it! I wish I knew jQuery that well ;)

Comment: it's only a matter of time ;) -- please accept the answer if it works for you. Cheers!